# LibGDX - How to integrate AdMob for both iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, libgdx, robovm

I am following [this](http://upandcrawling.wordpress.com/2013/07/29/libgdx-and-revmob-integration/) tutorial for AdMob integration through LibGDX, but it shows for Android only. I am just wondering if someone has an example how to achieve same integration including iOS? Also, how can I use banners instead of full screen?

Currently my setting for iOS with LibGDX is:

1.- RoboVM