# How to incorporate ads into libGDX

Tags: ios, libgdx, admob, ads

I've made a game, and now I'm looking into monetizing it. Using libGDX, I've exported it to Android and iOS, but I'm not sure of any way to put ads into it, Abmob for example, especially onto the iOS platform. Has anyone been in this position but was able to put ads in? If so, how exactly?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LibGDX - How to integrate AdMob for both iOS and Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025629/libgdx-how-to-integrate-admob-for-both-ios-and-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For how to implement platform specific code (iOS and android ads run differently) read this: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code

On how to implement admob on android read this: 
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

admob or mopub ads on libgdx roboVM backend (iOS backend) use these: 
https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings

Thats all you need to know. And yes a lot of people have been in your position and managed to implement ads on both mobile platforms. Including myself.

Comment: I'm not really sure how to use the bindings; when I import the admob project it states that the .proj file is missing. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: The RoboVM bindings are very much out of date btw.